# Download file/image after login website linux script

Tags: linux

When I directly paste the link to download, I need to login via below link and download the file through another link with the login-cookie

Login page http://metronetx.hgcbiz.com/npp/index.php

How can i make it in linux script?

Comment: tried this way but not work.


wget http://metronetx.hgcbiz.com/npp --post-data="login_username=***&login_password=***" --cookies=on --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies=cookie.txt

wget --referer="http://metronetx.hgcbiz.com/npp" --cookies=on --keep-session-cookies --load-cookies=cookie.txt http://metronetx.hgcbiz.com/npp/graph_image.php?action=view&local_graph_id=42206&rra_id=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hava a try about [webdriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/), write a script to control browser to finish this job.

Headless chrome is another good choose if you want run this job on server. 
[puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer)

It's the easiest way in my mind. But this will be inefficient if you have many files to download.

Comment: it is need to use window, i would like to use linux for this matter.